# Is it possible to use django-mptt and GenericForeignKey?

Tags: django, django-models, django-mptt

The model I'm using at the moment essentially has three classes. A root class, a tree attached to the root class and a leaf node class that can be attached anywhere in the tree.

e.g. Shop/Category/Product or Shop/Category/Category/Product

Product can only be linked to category.
Category can either be linked to another category or shop.

I would use a generic foreign key to link the category to the shop or another category, but as Category is a tree it needs a TreeForeignKey field. I'm looking for example of how this can be done in models.py or an alternative way of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a GenericForeignKey for this.

Implement your mptt fk's as normal and use that for setting up the category trees and add an optional shop FK field to link to shops.

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    shop = ForeignKey(Shop, null=True, blank=True)

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a redundancy with the shop ForeignKeyField? Say you had 10000 categories, only a few would contain a shop ForeignKey. Also is ForeignKeyField a typo? From a naive perspective I thought that the idea of a GenericForeignKey is to replace having to have multiple (partially redundant) foreign keys.